# Вылет при запуске winform приложения на другом пк

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, winforms, install

Есть winform приложение, которое собрал при помощи утилиты от visual studio

`Visual studio installer`

установка приложения проходит успешно, все ресурсы и т.д остаются, есть файлы сериализации, в сборке они так же есть, но при запуске, оно включается секунды 2 висит и выключается, код который по идее должен работать при запуске, таймер запускает функцию в которой есть Task'и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможна ли такая ошибка из-за версии .Net? я собираю на 4.5, в реестре у себя смотрел не нашел такой, на другом компе та же ситуация

Comment: зайди в ивент логи компьютера. Там будет ошибка с которой вылетела апликуха. Без ошибки тебе точно никто не подскажет в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

Вам придется доработать код в Program.cs так

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    //подписка на возникновение неперехваченных исключений
    Application.ThreadException += Application_ThreadException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    //сообщения об ошибках будем писать в файл (его можно найти в папке где exe)
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(File.CreateText("log.txt")));
    Trace.AutoFlush = true;

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

    }

    private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message);
    }

    private static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Exception.Message);
    }
```

Можете в коде др. классов в "подозрительных местах" расставить вызовы `Trace.WriteLine()` и писать туда сообщения об ошибках или значения переменных и проч.
Ну, и придётся пересобрать и переустановить приложение на целевом компе.