# Написал на С# windows service, должен работать постоянно но после первого прогона закрывается

Tags: c#

Проблема в топ что метод Tick должен выполняться все время работы службы, а служба останавливается после первого выполнения почему тау?(

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsService4
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool SetServiceStatus(System.IntPtr handle, ref ServiceStatus serviceStatus);
        public Service1()
        {

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Thread myThread = new Thread(Tick); //Создаем новый объект потока (Thread)
            myThread.Start();

            // Update the service state to Start Pending.
            ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus();
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING;
            serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = 100000;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
            serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
            SetServiceStatus(this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus);



        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        private void Tick()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(60000);
                String host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
                logg("Имя хоста: " + host);
                System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(host).AddressList[0];
                string bufuerip = ip.ToString();
                logg("IP адресс хоста " + bufuerip);
                string[] words = bufuerip.Split('.');
                string podset = words[2];
                logg("Разбитый ip адрес " + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3]);
                string uri = "http://***************/indata.php?nt=" + podset;
                WebRequest webr = WebRequest.Create(uri);
                logg("Ответ от сайта: " + (HttpWebResponse)webr.GetResponse());
                HttpWebResponse resp = null;
                resp.Close();
                logg("Закрываем поток");
            }
        }

        private void logg(string v)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"D:\logistic.log", v);
        }

        public enum ServiceState
        {
            SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x00000001,
            SERVICE_START_PENDING = 0x00000002,
            SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 0x00000003,
            SERVICE_RUNNING = 0x00000004,
            SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 0x00000005,
            SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 0x00000006,
            SERVICE_PAUSED = 0x00000007,
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ServiceStatus
        {
            public int dwServiceType;
            public ServiceState dwCurrentState;
            public int dwControlsAccepted;
            public int dwWin32ExitCode;
            public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
            public int dwCheckPoint;
            public int dwWaitHint;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот это `HttpWebResponse resp = null;` приведет к ошибке в след.строке `resp.Close();` NullReferenceException

Comment: И еще пару замечаний: 1) вместо `Thread` лучше использовать `Task`, хотя бы по причине возможности нормально перехватывать ошибки и отменять в нужный момент задачи, 2) для логирования лучше использовать `Trace` а не, то безобразие, которое сочинили вы. 3) для приложения работающего с сетью необходимо использовать try/catch и по-видимому перехват UnhandledException как это можно сделать см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940037/222542).